# Conditional If statement over large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, logic, conditional-statements

I'm looking for the most straightforward way to retrieve information from data frame in R. The data frame contains several dates, Day 0, Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 4, Day 5, Day 6, Day 7, and Day 8. The events are listed on a specific date, and we are interested in finding events that occurred between any two consecutive days, as well as between dates where a null entry exists (e.e. in the table below this would include between Day 3 and Day 5 in row 1).

```
    Person  day0 day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6  day7 events
     1      10   12   14   18   NA   22   32   50     20
     2      11   15   19   NA   NA   NA   50   67     35
     3      12   18   21   26   33   42   50   NA     45
     4      15   24   32   NA   43   NA   54   76     40
```

The full data set has several thousand people.

I attempted to check between the first two days and write the event to a vector:

```
for(i in 1:length(days$Person)){
if(days$event[i] != NA){
if(days$day0[i] != NA){
if(days$day1[i] != NA){

 if(days$day0[i] < days$events[i] & days$day1[i] > days$events[i]){
     vector[i]<-events[i]
}
}
}
```

However, I continue to get errors.

> Error in if (days$day1[i] != NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Error in if (days$day1[i] != NA) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Expected output would just be a vector with the date of the event.

Comment: `variable != NA` is wrong, use `!is.na(variable)`.

Comment: Your first `if` is `if(days$event[i] != NA)` when it should be `events` with a final `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is better to use `data.frame` subsetting than `for` loop and nested `if`;
- I added an observation into `data.frame` which meets your filter criteria, otherwise the output of your example is empty;
- If you add `NA` to any number the result is `NA`, `!is.na(events + day0 + day1)` is a shortened version of three nested `if`.
- You should use function `is.na` for `NA` check, since e.g. `10 != NA` returns `NA`.
- `if`-condition throws an error you mentiond, if you provide it with `NA`.
- It is better to use `dput(head(your_data.frame))` to provide an example of your input data as well as desired output, it will facilitate to get help from the community.

Please see the code below:

```
days <- structure(list(Person = 1:5, day0 = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 1L), 
    day1 = c(12L, 15L, 18L, 24L, 20L), day2 = c(14L, 19L, 21L, 
    32L, 3L), day3 = c(18L, NA, 26L, NA, 4L), day4 = c(NA, NA, 
    33L, 43L, 5L), day5 = c(22L, NA, 42L, NA, 6L), day6 = c(32L, 
    50L, 50L, 54L, 7L), day7 = c(50L, 67L, NA, 76L, 8L), events = c(20L, 
    35L, 45L, 40L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
vector <- subset(days, !is.na(events + day0 + day1) & day0 < events & day1 > events)[["events"]]
vector
```

Output is a vector of numbers of events meeting your criteria:

```
# [1] 10
```